# Error in or another way of calculating $\frac{1}{2} \in \mathbb{Q}_3$

Tags: number-theory, p-adic-number-theory

I want to find the $p$-adic expansion of $\frac{1}{2} \in \mathbb{Q}_3$. I begin with noting that $- \frac{1}{2} = \frac{1}{1-3} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} 3^n$. Therefore, $\frac{1}{2} = 1 - \frac{1}{2} = 2 + 3 + 3^2 + \ldots$. So far so good. However; Note that $$\frac{1}{2}= -4 \cdot \frac{1}{1-3^2} = -4 \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} 3^{2n} = -4(1 + 3^2 + 3^4 + \cdots ).$$ I'm relatively new at the $p$-adic theory, but as I understand it, the coefficients all have to be considered modulo $p$, so in this case $-4 = 2$. So where did I went wrong?

As always, any help would be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT** As pointed out, it's a really big error just to set $-4=2$. However, if one should choose to continue with the reasoning that $$1/2 = -4\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} 3^{2n},$$ how could one then find a $p$-adic expansion of $1/2$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This "gotcha" illustrates a feature that has deceived many people: yes, a $p$-adic integer *has* what looks like a sort of power series expansion $\sum_{n\ge 0} c_n\cdot p^n$ with $0\le c_n<p$, but these expansions do not behave stably under addition or multiplication. That is, regrouping or rearranging is required to put the result of such operations back in this form. Also, there are many *other* (convergent!) expansions of $p$-adic numbers (as this example illustrates), much like there are many other expansions of real numbers beside decimal expansions $\sum c_n/10^n$ with $0\le c_n\le 9$.

Altogether, the situation argues for not thinking of $p$-adic numbers as being "exactly" those special expansions, although that does give a transitional viewpoint. Instead, a $p$-adic integer is "represented" by any *sequence* of ordinary integers $a_n$, such that $a_{n+1}=a_n \mod p^n$. Correctly-enough, this makes things look a bit different from the real numbers.

Comment: So there's no apparent way to continue with this $-4$?

Comment: That sum you wrote is a legitimate, _convergent_ $3$-adic series. If you mean to require rearranging to have coefficients all in the range $0,1,2$, then, yes, there's work to do. But there is no such requirement. Your first computation was fine, as was your second (apart from mistakenly thinking $-4=2$ $3$-adically). There are many correct sums-of-series in the $3$-adic numbers, just as in the real numbers...

Answer (score 2):

If $a_k=b_k$ for all $k\ne n$ and $a_n=b_n+c$ then $\sum a_k3^k=3^nc+\sum b_k3^k$ so that $\sum a_k3^k\ne\sum b_k3^k$ if $c\ne0$, even if $3\mid c$. Thus you cannot use $-4=2$ just like that here.

Comment: I thought that was the really big error I couldn't quite see. However, suppose you want to continue with the reasoning that $-4 (1 + 3^2 + 3^4 + \cdots ) = 1/2$, should one then first find the $p$-adic extension of $-4$ to get a $p$-adic extension for 1/2?

Comment: Well, $4=1+3$ so you get again that $-(1+3+3^2+3^3+\ldots)=\frac12$